# Класс, который умеет парсить DOC\DOCX документы

Tags: doc, docx, парсер, php, symfony2

Подскажите PHP класс\скрипт\плагин , который умеет парсить DOC\DOCX документы.
(без использования сторонних сервисов)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://habrahabr.ru/post/119551/ - там есть пару способов решить проблему.